# How to transform this grammar to LR(1)?

Tags: parsing, lr-grammar

I have a grammar with an LR(1) conflict which I cannot resolve; yet, the grammar should be unambiguous. I'll first demonstrate the problem on a simplified grammar with five tokens: `(`, `)`, `{}`, `,` and `id`.

The EBNF would look like this:

```
      args = ( id ',' )*

expression = id
           | '(' expression ')'
           | '(' args ')' '{}'
```

The grammar is unambiguous and requires at most two tokens of lookahead. When `(` is shifted, there are only five possibilities:

1. `(` → Recur.
2. `)` → Reduce as `'(' args ')'`.
3. `id` `)` not `{}` → Reduce as `'(' expression ')'`.
4. `id` `)` `{}` → Reduce as `'(' args ')' '{}'`
5. `id` `,` → Reduce as `'(' args ')' '{}'` (eventually).

A naive translation yields the following result (and [conflicts](https://gist.github.com/whitequark/1d530b7da1a8324ba6a3#file-test-conflicts)):

```
   formal_arg: Ident
               {}

  formal_args: formal_arg Comma formal_args
             | formal_arg
             | /* nothing */
               {}

      primary: Ident
             | LParen formal_args Curly
             | LParen primary RParen
               {}
```

So, the grammar requires at most three tokens of lookahead to decide. I know that an LR(3) grammar [can be transformed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser) to LR(1) grammar.

However, I don't quite understand how to do the transformation in this particular case. Note that the simplified grammar above is an extraction from a [larger body of code](https://gist.github.com/whitequark/8f9b337e506664796f83); in particular, is it possible to transform  `primary` without touching `expr` and everything above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provided a solution to a problem very similar to this one here: [Is C#'s lambda expression grammar LALR(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928725/is-cs-lambda-expression-grammar-lalr1/16931641#16931641). The basic idea was to separate out the `( id )` case from the other two possibilities ( `( expr_not_id )` and `( list_at_least_2_ids )` ). Then the decision about how to reduce `( id )` can be deferred until the lookahead token is available (in your case, `{`, assuming that that is sufficient).

Unfortunately, while the transformation of `expr` into `expr_not_id` is pretty straightforward and almost mechanical, it definitely touches a lot of productions. Also, it's somewhat ugly. So it fails to solve the problem you present in the last sentence. I don't actually think that it is possible to transform `primary` without touching `expr`, but I've been surprised before.

(The other obvious solution, since the grammar is in fact unambiguous, is to use a GLR parser-generator, but I don't believe the parser-generator you are using has that feature.)

Comment: In fact I just came to the same conclusion as you. However, my parser generator (menhir) has higher-order rules, so I can let it do the grunt work for me. I will probably answer the question myself (if it works for me), sorry for not accepting!

Comment: The funniest part is that I know the author of the question you've linked to.

Comment: I just went with your transformation and it works, though required a set of strange transformations to the grammar. Awesome.