# Parser: Distinguish parenthesis and function declaration in JavaScript like grammar

Tags: parsing, ocaml, grammar, menhir

I'm working on a compiler using OCaml and Menhir as parser and lexer. When I'm writing a JavaScript like Grammar, with `(a, b) => a + b` like lambda function definition and also arithmetics `(a + b) * c` with parenthesis prioritizing sub-expressions, I write

```
expr
: x = ID { EId(x) }
...
| LPAREN; e = expr; RPAREN; { e }
...
| LPAREN; args = separated_list(COMMA, ID); RPAREN; ARROW; body = expr; { EFunction(args, body) }
```

in `parser.mly`.

Just adding few more context, I have my `lexer.mll` like this:

```
let letter = ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z']
let lud = ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z' '_' '0'-'9']
let id = letter lud*

rule read = parse
    ...
    | "(" { LPAREN }
    | ")" { RPAREN }
    | "," { COMMA }
    | "=>" { ARROW }
    ...
    | id { ID (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf) }
    ...
```

But this is going to get a reduce/reduce error when compile:

```
Error: do not know how to resolve a reduce/reduce conflict between the following two productions:
expr -> ID
separated_nonempty_list(COMMA,ID) -> ID
```

I know that the problem is probably caused by the ambiguity between these two: `(a)` and `(a) => a` (one-arg-function). But I still couldn't understand why it is still producing this error since to me it is super clear that the parenthesis followed by a fat arrow `=>` is going to be a function...

Can someone help me a bit on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I still couldn't understand why it is still producing this error since to me it is super clear that the parenthesis followed by a fat arrow `=>` is going to be a function...

Yes, it is super clear. The grammar is totally unambiguous. But you are not limited to looking at the input one token at a time, whereas an LR(**1**) parser is. At the moment when the parser is trying to decide what to do about the `a` in `(a)`, it cannot yet seen the fat arrow and it has to make its decision before it does. That is, before consuming the <kbd>)</kbd>, the parser needs to decide whether what comes before it is an `expr` or a `separated_nonempty_list`.

It's possibly worth noting that the grammar is actually LR(2): one more lookahead token, and the conflict could be resolved. That's not much consolation since Menhir does not provide any mechanism for increased lookahead, but it does mean that a solution exists, because the existence of an LR(k) grammar for a language implies the existence of an LR(1) grammar for the same language; there's even a mechanical algorithm to produce the LR(1) grammar.

Rather than transforming the entire grammar, an only slightly messy solution is to isolate the '(a)` cases, which can be done with a pair of apparently redundant rules:

```
expr: LPAREN ID RPAREN ARROW expr
    | LPAREN ID RPAREN
```

The second production obviously conflicts with `LPAREN expr RPAREN`, but it's a shift/reduce conflict rather than a reduce/reduce conflict and it can be resolved by giving `RPAREN` a higher precedence than `ID` in order to force resolution in favour of shifting `RPAREN`.

That's a complete perversion of precedence declarations, and it may well prove to be problematic as your grammar gets more complicated. A more theoretically sound solution would be to define `expr_other_than_identifier`. You can find an example of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16931641/1566221), which is a very similar grammar,  and in some other SO answers to similar questions.

In particular, Yacc's own grammar is LR(2) (you can't tell that a rule has ended until you see the `:` following the non-terminal which starts the next rule). A similar solution exists for this grammar, but most yacc-like parser generators solve the problem by pushing the extra lookahead into the lexer analyzer. For example, you could recognize `) =>` as a single token (including the internal whitespace), or you could issue a different close parenthesis token if the next token were a fat arrow.