# C# 5.0 EBNF grammar

Tags: c#, ebnf

I am looking for an EBNF grammar of the programming language C# in the Version 5.0. This grammar should be machine readable, so I am able to do some processing with this EBNF grammar

Until now I found out that the language specification document of C# is included in the installation of Visual Studio (`%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Specifications\1033`) this document already includes the BNF grammar embedded in the document. However, this is only in BNF syntax and not EBNF and it is embedded in the *.docx document an no separate file, which means it is not sufficient for me.

Additionally I found these resources:

- [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2010/04/19/grammar.aspx): This is a EBNF grammar for C# version 4.0
- [slps.github.io](http://slps.github.io/zoo/#Cs_4.0): This contains the extracted BNF Grammar for C# Version 4.0

So these resources are not sufficient for my project. Do you know a complete EBNF grammar for C# 5.0?

Comment: Which variant of EBNF are you using?  The one given in MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(v=vs.71).aspx) is a mix of W-grammar and BNF which some might call EBNF but this is the C#2.0 specification.

Comment: Ideally ISO/IEC 14977:1996(E). Basically the variant used in this link http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/cse4251/mini_java_grammar.html which specifies a EBNF grammar for MiniJava

Comment: Doubt you will find one in that variant.  There is a complete grammar specification in one of the back appendices of http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029 .  It is probably the one in ProgramFiles.  Easiest way is probably to copy the appendix and use global search and replace or a powershell/awk script to convert it to a form that is usable to you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, you are right, its exactly the same document which is shipped with Visual Studio. I hoped that I could skip this manual step, but if there is no EBNF grammar I have to do it...

Comment: I'm curious what you intend to accomplish once you find the grammar.

Answer (score 3):

I know you're looking for a C# 5.0 Grammar, but there is an `ANTLR` grammar for c# 6.0 at [github](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp). `ANTLR` uses a kind of EBNF notation and can be parsed by a computer. If you want ANTLR allows you to generate a parser for C# from that grammar. Since C# 6.0 is a superset of C# 5.0, the Version difference shouldn't matter.